# PHPTAL Nested Repeat

Tags: php, template-tal, phptal

I am having an problem trying to achieve a nested repeat in PHPTAL:

```
    <tr tal:repeat="business analysis_result">
 <td>${business/trading_name}</td>
 <tal:block tal:repeat="selected_key selected_keys">
  <td>HOW??????</td>                               <---problem
 </tal:block>
</tr>
```

basically I want to have the `<td>` of inner repeat to get the value of `$business[$selected_key]`, I have looked at the phptal manual which doesn't really give you a demo on how to do this.

Comment: ok I found an answer to my own question.
<td tal:content="PHP: business[selected_key]"></td>

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<tr tal:repeat="business analysis_result">
    <td>${business/trading_name}</td>
    <tal:block tal:repeat="selected_key business/selected_keys">
    <td tal:content="selected_key"/>
    </tal:block>
</tr>
```

Imagine if you were using php instead of some new language you have to learn! Imagine how easy it would be!

Comment: sorry this doesn't work, because the selected_key holds the associative key of the business array

Answer (score 1):

```
<td tal:content="php:business[selected_key]"/>
```

or the "TAL way":

```
<td tal:content="business/${selected_key}"/>
```